# How do I dynamically publish collections via a Meteor method?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I dynamically create collections with this method:

```
createPlist: function(jid) {
      try {
            Plist[jid] = new Meteor.Collection(pid);
          } catch(e) {
            console.log("oops, I did it again");
          }
            Plist[jid].insert({
              ...,
              ...,
              public:true,
              uid:this.userId
            });
    }
```

Then I am wanting to publish these selectively, and I am attempting to do it via a method:

```
 getPlist: function(jid,pid) {
  // var future = new Future();


  try {
    Plist[jid] = new Meteor.Collection(pid);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("oops, I did it again");
  }
  Meteor.publish(pid, function() {
    console.log(Plist[jid].find({}));
    // future["return"](Plist[jid].find({}));
     return Plist[jid].find();

  });
  // return future.wait();
},
```

This returns 'undefined' to my Template helper, and returns nothing (i.e. waits forever) using Future.

Any user can log in and create a Plist collection, which can be either public or not. A user can also subscribe to any collection where public is true. The variable jid is passed to the method 'getPlist' from the template. It is stored in the user's Session.

Thanks! I hope I have explained it well enough!

And of course the template:

```
Template.plist.helpers({
 getPlist: function() {
 Pl = []
 jid = Session.get('jid');
 //alert(jid);
 pid = "pl_"+jid;
 // console.log(pid);
 Meteor.call('getPlist', jid, pid, function(err,res) {
  console.log(res); //returns undefined

  try {
    Pl[jid] = new Meteor.Collection(pid);  
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
   Meteor.subscribe(pid);
  // return Pl[jid].find({}).fetch();
 });
```

}

Comment: See the "Dynamically Created Collections" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes). TL;DR you really don't want to create dynamic collections because it's extremely complex to manage the collection state on any connected clients.

Comment: @DavidWeldon is right as usual. You should consider making this dynamic collection into a document of a `plist` collection. You are over complicating things.

Comment: I like the analogy with the diamonds in your article @DavidWeldon. I see your point I think.